# Need to right align divs child elements using css

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div containing 2 div's. One is aligned left and another one div aligned right. So each contains child elements.

```css
.card-middle-row  {
  
}
.card-middle-row .container-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.card-middle-row .container-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.card-middle-row .container-left span {
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.card-middle-row .container-right span {
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.card-middle-row > div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-middle-row">
    <div class="container-left">
      <div>Quantity</div>
      <div>
        <span>Cancelqty</span> Out of 100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-right">
      <div>Price</div>
      <div><span>order</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the problem is the div **container-right** contains the child elements. Due to the `<span>` tag the two child elements not properly aligned right.

Comment: So you want to align them into a single line, is that right?

Comment: The price and order child elements vertically align right side.

Comment: Yeah, so you want to make it horizontally aligned as `Cancelqty` and `Out of 100`?

Answer (score 3):

Add `text-align:right` to your `.container-right` seletor. Try this.

```
.card-middle-row .container-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: there is a difference between aligning boxes (div, header, footer, section) and text inside those boxes. If you want to align text inside your container, you need to use `text-align: left|center|right|justify`

Comment: Your property `float:right` would stick the whole `div` element `<div class="container-right">' to right but don't align the text (including `<span>` element to the right, so when you use `text-align:right`, the inline elements inside the block would align to right edge. I hope this would explain well. Also, check the explanation from @DomenikReitzner

Comment: if my answer works for you, ticking it as right answer would be good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use flex box

```
 .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Display Flex to keep everything in order.

```
.container-right{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```